# Can spambots access the web page that requires authentication?

Tags: email, security, web-crawler, bots

I am trying to protect user email address from web scraping.
The email address is only displayed on a web page when a user is logged in to his account.
So do i need to take certain precautions & try to hide the email address from spambots or there is no need to worry as the user needs to be logged in to see the email address.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing how the data is stored and subsequently accessed this question isn't possible to answer.

If you're using something like `$_SESSION` for verification once they've successfully logged in then I see no issue.

Comment: I am on a wordpress website & login/registration is managed by WP itself.
I read the source code & they set some kind of "authentication cookies"
I am not sure about that , but i guess wordpress has these basics security features.